# C++ Link Curl Statically

Tags: c++, curl, static, libcurl

I'm using this code in DEV C++ environment.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void){
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://google.com");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "TestAgent");
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

I have linked libcurldll.a and libcurl.a files. I can compile and run the code but the executable required msvcr70.dll and libcurl.dll in the same directory. How can I link them statically?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [`curl-config`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/using/curl-config.html) tool. It provides an option to get the linker flags and dependencies to build libcurl for static linking:

> #### --static-libs
>
> Shows the complete set of libs and other linker options you will need in order 
>   to link your application with libcurl statically. (Added in 7.17.1)

In order for doing so, you need to build libcurl from source on your environment.

Comment: Does this mean I have to build curl with proper flags, so I can link my program to curl statically ? isn't there any curl packages I need to install to accomplish this instead of building the curl ?

Comment: @Accountantم See my last paragraph: _"In order for doing so, you need to build libcurl from source on your environment."_